# How to start a workflow when someone appends changes to a multiple lines of text column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint list with a column (Migration Update Notes) that contains multiple lines of text (with the ability to append changes/versioning). Is there a way to initiate a workflow when someone appends new changes? I am trying to create a workflow that will send an email to the following names in Column OCR PM, BSC, Pri DBA, Sec DBA and Tech Mgr; if someone appends changes/text to the Migration Updates Notes.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp field to store the previous state of the textbox.

Create a workflow that fires every time there's a change.

if the temp field is Not equal to current perform your changes, the last action in the if condition has to be temp = current

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sharepoint 2010, use the 'Wait for *field* to **not** equal *value*. Where *value* will equal a previous copy of your Migrate Update Notes in a different, new column.

[![field=Migrate Update Notes
   value=previous Migrate update Notes
   these users=look-up to your five users][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giJnv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giJnv.jpg)

Comment: When trying to set the Current Item, the field "Migration Update Notes" does not appear in the drop down. Maybe because it is a multi-text based column with the ability to append changes?

Comment: That's interesting. The appended, multi-text properties shouldn't have an effect on being able to select it. I have a very similar workflow running with the same type of field without any issues.

Comment: Are all the other fields in your list showing up? If they are, try refreshing sharepoint designer. If the other fields are not showing up, make sure the workflow is connected to the correct list.

Comment: Ok when I refreshed SP Designer they showed up, weird. How can I set the Wait for field to NOT equal value. It is only giving me the option to set it as just equal. I am using SPD 2013. But wouldn't there need to be an additional step where it would set the Previous Migration notes to the Migration Update notes, just so if changes are made again the workflow will execute once more?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that you need to have step in which you set Previous Migration Notes to the value of Migration Notes. In my experience, it is best to use 'Return as string' for this and not 'as text'. And, unfortunately, SPD 2013 does not have the option for 'not equal to' like SPD 2010 did. I remember seeing some work-arounds on stackexchange and other sites, I'll post them here if I can find them.

Comment: This might be of use to you [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7eddf7c3-1dec-4369-8995-ec7a6123a70d/how-to-start-a-workflow-when-a-value-in-specific-column-is-changed?forum=sharepointcustomization)   I have not used SPD 2013 so I'm not much help there but using an 'If, then' statement may work.